# AngularJS and ( ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC )

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I want to build a Single Page Application using AngularJS as an client side framework but I struggle to understand if I can use the ASP.NET as my server side framework?

I know that AngularJS is an MVC framework and when I'm trying to decide wich server side framework to chose all I hear or read is MVC, MVC,...,MVC.

I know, this an subjective question, but still, can any one tell me if I need to learn ASP.NET MVC or I can still reach the desired result using the ASP.NET framework?

Comment: You can choose whatever backend you like, it really depends on what you're trying to do. Your SPA (frontend) can work with only html/css/javascript (no backend is needed for it, only the server that would provide the files). But for Web Api (which is used by your SPA) you can select various backend frameworks (be it ASP.NET, NodeJs or whatever)...

Comment: Ignore the MVC part for both front end and back end. That is just a architectural design pattern to enable clean maintainable code. The fact is they both serve different purposes. AngularJS for a rich client side application. ASP.NET MVC is a rich server side framework. You need both of them (and they can be used in conjunction) to create a full rich web application.

Comment: Thank you for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever technology you want.

Basically to be able to communicate with angular you need something that listen for http requests (an http server so), parse them and that can send/read json (with maybe some extra libraries). The static pages can just be deserves by an apache in front.

You could do that in C parsing the whole thing yourself, but for performance, maintenability, speed of development and a bunch of other reasons, it's better to use an appropriate framework.

If your application is not big-scaled, specially in the backend part just search for a c# rest framework that handle thing that url mapping and json.

Comment: That satisfies my curiosity. Tnx